# When i try to delete redundant file even after closing all the references jvm throws the FileSystemException

Tags: java, filesystems, javacv

I'm creating a video record file (avi) with [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) after creation converting this file to an mp4 file with [Jaffree](https://github.com/kokorin/Jaffree). When i try to delete the now redundant avi file it throws the FileSystemException.

I've already released all the file holding Objects but still the exception is being thrown. Also tried to force the deletion with apache common io `FileUtils.forceDelete(sample.getFile());` still having the same Exception.

---

```
public class PacketRecorderTest {

private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd__hhmmSSS");
private static final int RECORD_LENGTH = 10000;
private static final boolean AUDIO_ENABLED = false;
static String inputFile =  "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
static String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\team3\\Desktop\\User\\Vinay\\javacppffmpeg\\frame.avi";

public static void main(String[] args) throws FrameRecorder.Exception, FrameGrabber.Exception, InterruptedException{
    packetRecord(inputFile,outputFile);
    jafreeToMp4(outputFile, "C:\\Users\\team3\\Desktop\\User\\Vinay\\javacppffmpeg\\frame.mp4");
    try {
        Files.delete(Paths.get(outputFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void packetRecord(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws FrameGrabber.Exception, FrameRecorder.Exception {

    FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputFile);
    grabber.start();
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(
            outputFile,
            1280,
            720);
    recorder.start(grabber.getFormatContext());
    recorder.setFormat("avi");
    recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    recorder.setVideoOption("crf", "22");
    recorder.setVideoQuality(0);
    recorder.setFrameRate(15);
    recorder.start();

    avcodec.AVPacket packet;
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ((packet = grabber.grabPacket()) != null) {
            recorder.recordPacket(packet);
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) > RECORD_LENGTH) {
                break;
            }
    }
    grabber.stop();
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    grabber.release();

}


public static void jafreeToMp4 (String inputFile, String outputFile) {
    Path BIN = Paths.get("C:\\ffmpeg\\shared\\bin");
    Path VIDEO_MP4 = Paths.get(inputFile);
    Path OUTPUT_MP4 = Paths.get(outputFile);

    FFmpegResult result = FFmpeg.atPath(BIN)
            .addInput(UrlInput.fromPath(VIDEO_MP4))
            .addOutput(UrlOutput.toPath(OUTPUT_MP4)
            )
            .execute();
}
```

}

---

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\team3\Desktop\User\Vinay\javacppffmpeg\frame.avi: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at playground.PacketRecorderTest.main(PacketRecorderTest.java:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, as I don't have immediate access to the libraries you're using.  However, it looks to me as though you still have open `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams`.  My suggestions would look something like this, depending on the return type of the helper methods:

```
try(InputStream in = UrlInput.fromPath(VIDEO_MP4);
    OutputStream out = UrlOutput.toPath(OUTPUT_MP4)) {

    FFmpegResult result = FFmpeg.atPath(BIN)
        .addInput(in)
        .addOutput(out)
        .execute();
}
```

This will close the resources after the statement is complete.

Comment: It's not exactly the jafreeToMp4() method but the packetRecord() itself is holding the file, Tried doing  this  `try ( FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputFile);
                FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(
                outputFile,
                1280,
                720)
        ) { ... }` . Didn't help though :(

Answer (score 0):

Was calling the start() method twice `recorder.start(grabber.getFormatContext());` and `start()`. So may the first call may have left the references untracked.